# Can I modify the "compare branch" of a pull request?

Tags: github

I have an open pull request with many comments.

I want to change the branch it is comparing against (not the base branch) while still keeping the review comments (See below why).

Is it possible to do that?
If so, how? 
Also, which permissions are needed?

====

Why would this help me?
I messed up my pull request branch:
I switched from using merge to using rebase, which messed up my pull-request branch (I'm now seeing other pr's commits in my pull request changes).

So, I'd like to create a clean branch off master and reapply my changes.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to create a clean branch off master and reapply my changes --- isn't this correct and solution? why need 'modify the compare branch'?

Comment: I want to keep the review comments. Yes, a workaround would be to create a new pr and mention the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be to create a new "correct" branch from master and force-push it to the old branch.
This will remove any unwanted commit which doesn't exist in the "correct" branch.